# Macros #if directive with non integer definition

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I'm having a 20yo legacy code (pure C) which defines:

```
#define X float
```

before first function and before another function:

```
#undefine X
#define X double
```

I'm writing a code which is supposed to work with both definitions (and it'll be copied into both functions automatically). But it's impossible to make such code in a few cases. For these cases I need to detect if my X is float or double and use `#if #else #endif`.

The `#if (X == float)` is resolved as `0 == 0` and won't work.
In theory I can grab into legacy code and modify these definition to make my life easier, but I wonder if there is any macro magic which would allow me to workaround this without touching the legacy? Something with conversion X to string may be? Any ideas?

Comment: A bit off topic, but I'm curious what kind of things you're talking about that you can't make work in this context without conditional compilation.

Comment: Also, are you compiling your legacy code with a legacy compiler or otherwise against a legacy version of the language?  Because if you're compiling as C11 or later then you can very likely employ type-generic expressions instead of conditional compilation.

Comment: I'm compiling the code where all headers and function declarations are generated with old code-generator written in C and it uses a lot of macro. It generates double/float versions, java, c# function definition etc. (I'm not sure if anything other than C is still needed to anyone as the lib is used mostly in python via standalone wrapper project). And implementation of a function is cloned by this generator to other versions of this function. The sample: https://github.com/TA-Lib/ta-lib/blob/master/src/ta_func/ta_STDDEV.c  The macro definition which was the problem is INPUT_TYPE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenate with prefix that expands to something you can control.

```
#define PREFIX_float   0
#define PREFIX_double  1
#define CONCAT(a, b)   a##b
#define XCONCAT(a, b)  CONCAT(a, b)

#if XCONCAT(PREFIX_, X) == PREFIX_float
```